# Timer still running after cancel()

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am making a digital clock in flutter.
I am using Timer() to print current time and update UI every second, using Riverpod for UI.
The issue is that when I click back and exit the page, the timer successfully closes. But this 'Error Code' is recurring every second. maybe Timer is Not infact closed at all ? How stop it from running in backgound.

my full code is:

```dart
    
class TimerClockQuestion extends ConsumerWidget {
  final myStateProviderTime2 = StateProvider((ref) => 'state time');

  Timer? timerClock2;
  String currentTime = '12:00 AM';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    runTimerClock(ref);
    currentTime = ref.watch(myStateProviderTime2);


    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          currentTime ,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white38),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void runTimerClock(WidgetRef ref){
    timerClock2?.cancel();
    timerClock2 = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      currentTime = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss a').format(DateTime.now());
      ref.read(myStateProviderTime2.notifier).state = currentTime;
      print(currentTime);
    });
  }
}
```

Error message is

```
Error: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4241:9                                                                         <fn>
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4254:14                                                                        [_debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4286:12                                                                        getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType
packages/flutter_riverpod/src/framework.dart 101:22                                                                        containerOf
packages/flutter_riverpod/src/consumer.dart 607:59                                                                         read
packages/riverpod_prc/ponds/state/timer_clock_question.dart 30:3                                                           <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 80:17       <fn>
```

Comment: I think you should change `timerClock2?.cancel();` to `timerClock2!.cancel();` and see if that'd work

Comment: it seems that the problem is related to how you manage your state, not specificly timer.cancel().

Comment: Why not use `ConsumerStatefulWidget` and override `dispose()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your timer gets cancelled every time your widget builds but not when it's diposed (when you click on back).
The solution would be to use a stateful widget, store the timer in the state and cancel it in the dispose method.